# jQuery: not filter

Tags: jquery, filter

Suppose I have a menu and when I am hovering specific element on the menu `#sub`: another menu is sliding down `.subnav`.

how can I achieve that:

when ('.subnav') is down and i am not hovering him and and also not hovering ('#sub'), ('.subnav') will slide up.

i tried to do that with not filter .

*Html*:

```
<ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="sub"><a href="#">slide</a>   
            <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
</ul>
```

*Js*:

```
 $('.topnav #sub').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.subnav').slideDown('fast');

    $(':not(#sub,#subnav)').hover(function () {
        $('#sub .subnav').slideUp('fast');
    });      
});
```

Thanks a lot(and please explain the best way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(':not(#sub,#subnav)').hover(function () {` basically means "when anything that is *not* `#sub` or `#subnav`, do something (additionally, you're attaching the handler several times)

What you want is

```
$("#sub").hover(
  function(){
    $(this).children('.subnav').slideDown('fast');
  },function(){
    $(this).children('.subnav').slideUp('fast');
  }
}
```

`jQuery#hover` takes one or two functions as arguments. If two functions are supplied, the first one is called on mouse enter, and the second one is called on mouse leave. If one function is supplied, it is called on both occasions.
Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Note that if `.subnav` is hovered, so is `#sub`, so you don't need to check both.

Comment: Thanks, can u please explain  function(){},function(){}

Comment: `$.hover` takes up two arguments. One when `mouseover` and the next when `mouseout`.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt even know that hover takese 2 args, if i use toggle instead it will be the same apart of the slide effect right?              $(this).children('.subnav').toggle('fast');

Comment: @slash1z using `slideToggle` is an option as well. I, however, consider `slideToggle` more fragile than `slideUp/slideDown`

Comment: What do u mean by saying "fragile", it's not supposed to be the same? as slideDown and slideup?

Comment: @slash1z `slideToggle` will slide up if the element is visible, slide down otherwise. `slideUp/slideDown` will slide up when the element loses hover, slide down when it gains focus. If you accidentally slide once more (or you don't complete a slide) your element will start sliding up on hover and down on unhover. That's what I call "fragile".

Answer (score 0):

#### You can actually do it using CSS

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id="sub"><a href="#">slide</a>   
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

#### Now for your CSS

```
#sub:hover .subnav {display: block;}
```

As simple as that.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ks22d/

---

#### Else if you want animation using jQuery, just tweak this code:

```
$(document)​.ready(function(){
    $("#sub").children('.subnav').hide();
    $("#sub").hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.subnav').slideDown('fast');
    }, function(){
        $(this).children('.subnav').slideUp('fast');
    });
});​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ks22d/1/

*ps: Inspired by [Jan Dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499214/jan-dvorak)'s answer...*

Comment: This won't do the animation.

Comment: Yeah. I know. Have added the animation part too. @JanDvorak

Comment: Tell me, were you inspired by my answer when writing the second part of yours?

Comment: Yeah... Now changed it totally! :)

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo 1](http://jsbin.com/osojof/4/edit)***

```
$('.topnav #sub').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.subnav').stop().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

OR if you like it fancy ;)

***[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/osojof/1/edit)***

```
$('.topnav #sub').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( e ) {
    var slideDir = e.type=='mouseenter' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp';
    $(this).find('.subnav').stop()[slideDir]('fast');
});
```

Comment: Using dynamic method names (box notation) is usually not very readable. You're taking it a step further by using it together with chaining ;-)

Comment: You can crank it up a bit even: `.stop()[{mouseenter:'slideDown', mouseleave:'slideUp'}[e.type]]('fast')` :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak feel free to add a new sample to my answer ;) looks like we both like madness

Comment: I'd rather not see this used in practice :-) (at least not with the map being inline)